# kube-dns not working on kubernetes arm

Tags: docker, dns, arm, kubernetes

I deploy a kubernetes cluster following the guide: https://blog.hypriot.com/post/setup-kubernetes-raspberry-pi-cluster/. It basically uses hypriotOS and kubernetes from the debian repository.

After the deployment, all the pods were running and no faults were shown. However, the dns server was not working properly on the worker node.

**master**

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get svc   
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns               10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   34m
kubernetes-dashboard   10.103.97.112   <nodes>       80:30518/TCP    31m 

# I installed the dnsutils to have the dig command
$ dig @10.96.0.10 || echo "FAIL"
# shows a valid response (note that we are not resolving anything)
```

**worker**

```
$ dig @10.96.0.10 || echo "FAIL"
....
FAIL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turn out that the answer was in one of the [comments](https://blog.hypriot.com/post/setup-kubernetes-raspberry-pi-cluster/#comment-3142210207) from , but it was not clear that this was my issue.

As the author of the comment stated is due to the iptables policies from Docker versions > 1.13.

To solve it, execute the following on both nodes:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i cni0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o cni0 -j ACCEPT
```